# Export-PowerBIReport giving error "Export-PowerBIReport : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'"

Tags: powershell, powerbi

When I am trying to access Export-PowerBIReport to export .pbix report file I am getting error "Export-PowerBIReport : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'".

I have PowerBI PRO account.
I have install all power BI modules.Below is the code I have used . Please suggest.

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount
$wrkSpace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name 'xxxx'
$rep1 = Get-PowerBIReport  -Name "Report Test1" -WorkspaceId $wrkSpace.id 
$rep1
$rep1ID = [guid]$rep1.Id
$rep1GUID = $rep1ID.guid
$wrkSpace.id 
$temp_path ='C:\test\test1.pbix' 
Export-PowerBIReport -Id $rep1ID  -WorkspaceId $wrkSpace.id -OutFile $temp_path
```

Comment: Did you forget a closing `"` on `$rep1 = Get-PowerBIReport  -Name <#here >#>"Report Test1' -WorkspaceId $wrkSpace.id`?

Comment: its just a typo in actual code i have it correct

Comment: Why you are passing `$rep1ID` to `Export-PowerBIReport`? It looks your intention is to pass `$rep1GUID` instead.

Comment: Even if I pass $rep1GUID i am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Incremental refresh was set on the report that is why it could not be exported.